# R: How to do calculations on a prior row in a dataframe without using a loop?

Tags: r

How can I calculate cumulative Heating Degree Days without using a For loop statement? I'm new to R and am not quite sure how get this done.

I want to do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$cumHDD <- df$HeatingDegreeDay[i] + df$cumHDD[i-1]
     i <- i+1
}
```

Below is my data.

```
    SiteID SubstrateID  WinterID       Date HeatingDegreeDay cumHDD
1   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-01        0.0000000      0
2   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-02        0.0000000      0
3   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-03        0.0000000      0
4   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-04        0.0000000      0
5   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-05        0.0000000      0
6   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-06        0.0000000      0
7   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-07        0.0000000      0
8   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-08        0.0000000      0
9   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-09        0.0000000      0
10  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-10        0.0000000      0
11  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-11        0.0000000      0
12  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-12        0.0000000      0
13  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-13        0.0000000      0
14  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-14        0.0000000      0
15  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-15        0.0000000      0
16  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-16        0.0000000      0
17  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-17        0.0000000      0
18  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-18        0.0000000      0
19  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-19        0.3724242      0
20  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-20        0.0000000      0
21  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-21        0.0000000      0
22  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-22        0.0000000      0
23  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-23        0.2773077      0
24  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-24        0.2679310      0
25  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-25        0.0000000      0
```

So, for my data above, when it's done correctly, it should look like this:

```
SiteID SubstrateID  WinterID       Date HeatingDegreeDay cumHDD
1   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-01        0.0000000      0
2   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-02        0.0000000      0
3   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-03        0.0000000      0
4   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-04        0.0000000      0
5   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-05        0.0000000      0
6   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-06        0.0000000      0
7   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-07        0.0000000      0
8   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-08        0.0000000      0
9   NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-09        0.0000000      0
10  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-10        0.0000000      0
11  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-11        0.0000000      0
12  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-12        0.0000000      0
13  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-13        0.0000000      0
14  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-14        0.0000000      0
15  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-15        0.0000000      0
16  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-16        0.0000000      0
17  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-17        0.0000000      0
18  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-18        0.0000000      0
19  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-19        0.3724242      0.3724242
20  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-20        0.0000000      0.3724242
21  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-21        0.0000000      0.3724242
22  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-22        0.0000000      0.3724242
23  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-23        0.2773077      0.6497319
24  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-24        0.2679310      0.9176629
25  NW_SB           B 2002_2003 2002-11-25        0.0000000      0.9176629
```

Can I do this within a `ddply` statement? I had some other functions to do and thought it would be nice to also do the above within a `ddply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `cumsum` for that:

```
mydata$cumHDD<-with(mydata,cumsum(HeatingDegreeDay))
```

Assuming mydata is your data.

Example with mtcars data using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
mydata<-mtcars
k<-ddply(mydata,.(cyl),summarize,cummpg=cumsum(mpg))
```

> head(k,10)

```
cyl cummpg
1    4   22.8
2    4   47.2
3    4   70.0
4    4  102.4
5    4  132.8
6    4  166.7
7    4  188.2
8    4  215.5
9    4  241.5
10   4  271.9
```

Comment: Thank you, @Metric, that's perfect. I'm loving R! Thanks for teaching me something new today!